# Getting values from columns based on user selection

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Using WTForms, SQLAlchemy I'm trying to have the user select a **Country** keyword from a dropdown and from that choice we pass the coordinates (west, south, east, north) of that country back to the program.

Been stuck on how this can be done as the `choices=GeoKeywords.label` passes the country fine.  Selecting "Albania" passes the value "Albania".  But how can I bring in west, south, east, north based on that selection?

Database Table:

[image]

```
GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS= Table('GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS', Base.metadata,
                Column('VALUE', String(75)),
                 Column('LABEL', String(75)),
                     Column('WEST', String(50)),
                     Column('SOUTH', String(50)),
                     Column('NORTH', String(50)),
                     Column('EAST', String(50)))

class GeoKeywords():
s = select([GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.VALUE, GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.LABEL])
result = connection.execute(s)
label = [row for row in result]

class ReusableForm(Form): 
     region = SelectField('Geographic Keyword:', choices=GeoKeywords.label)

@app.route("/editorother", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def editorother():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        region = request.form['region']

        if form.validate():
        "Do stuff with region and coordinates"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another query which returns the NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, and WEST columns for the selected region.

```
...
if form.validate():
    coords_query = select([GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.NORTH, 
                           GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.EAST, 
                           GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.SOUTH,  
                           GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.WEST])
                   .where(GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.LABEL == region)
    result = connection.execute(coords_query)
    # result will be a list of matching rows with coordinates arranged in a tuple taking the same order as the 'select' statement 
    # e.g. (NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST)
...
```

Comment: I'm getting an unresolved reference to .where  How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

@shiv answer is very close and got me in the right direction, I will mark it as the answer though you will need to edit the `.where` placement.  In the end this worked:

```
class Coodinator:
    def coordinates_query(self):
        self.coords_select = select([GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.WEST,
                                 GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.SOUTH, GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.EAST,
                                 GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.NORTH])

        self.coords_select = self.coords_select.where(GP_DD_GEOKEYWORDS.c.LABEL == region)
        self.coords_row = connection.execute(self.coords_select)

                for row in self.coords_row:
                    self.coords_row = dict(row)

        def coordinates_west(self):
                return self.coords_row['WEST']
```